# How can I protect Org spreadsheet columns from calculation?

Tags: org-mode, spreadsheet

Consider:

#### Before

```
| plan      |  a | b | c |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| concern 1 | -1 | 0 | 2 |
| concern 2 |  2 | 1 | 1 |
| concern 3 |  0 | 2 | 1 |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| score:    |    |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @>=vsum(@I..@II)
```

#### After

```
| plan      |  a | b | c |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| concern 1 | -1 | 0 | 2 |
| concern 2 |  2 | 1 | 1 |
| concern 3 |  0 | 2 | 1 |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| 6 concern |  1 | 3 | 4 |
#+TBLFM: @>=vsum(@I..@II)
```

After the table is recalculated, my `score:` identifier is changed to `6 concern` (no doubt the sum of `concern 1..3`).  How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
| plan      |  a | b | c |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| concern 1 | -1 | 0 | 2 |
| concern 2 |  2 | 1 | 1 |
| concern 3 |  0 | 2 | 1 |
|-----------+----+---+---|
| score:    |  1 | 3 | 4 |
#+TBLFM: @>$<<..$>=vsum(@I..@II)
```

`$<<..$>` means "the range of columns starting from the second and up to the last."

See [References](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) in the Org Manual for more.

Tested using `Org-mode version 8.3.3 (8.3.3-51-g30bcff-elpa)` and `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`.

Comment: That does the trick! Funny, I didn't come across that section in the manual. I must have missed it. Thanks for the reference!